# Saving image file to a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, chaquopy

I am receiving an image as bytes that I would like to store using specifically with open command due to library restrictions. Therefore I am unable to use libs like opencv2 and PIL

```
mport numpy as np
import base64
import cv2
import io
from os.path import dirname, join
from com.chaquo.python import Python

def main(data):
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)

    files_dir = str(Python.getPlatform().getApplication().getFilesDir())
    filename = join(dirname(files_dir), 'image.PNG')

    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        img = file.write(img)

    return img
```

What I would simply like to do is save the image file to the current directory that i am in.
Currently when i try my code it gives me the following error:

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Which requires me to have a string. I'd like to know what do i need to do to save the image as a .PNG file to the directory

Comment: have you tried with opencv, you can use cv2.imwrite("img.png",img) instead of file.write().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
out_file = open(filename, 'wb')
out_file.write(decoded_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

by using with statement, the opened file after processing will be closed automatically

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
   file.write(decode_data)
```